# Using twisted to process files

Tags: python, xml, twisted, file-transfer

I'm trying to set up a twisted xmlrpc server, which will accept files from a client, process them, and return a file and result dictionary back.

I've used python before, but never the twisted libraries. For my purposes security is a non issue, and the ssh protocol seems like overkill. It also has problems on the windows server, since `termios` is not available.

So all of my research points to xmlrpc being the best way to accomplish this. However, there are two methods of file transfer available. Using the `xml binary data` method, or the `http request` method.

Files can be up to a few hundred megs either way, so which method should I use? Sample code is appreciated, since I could find no documentation for file transfers over xml with twisted.

**Update:**

So it seems that serializing the file with `xmlrpclib.Binary` does not work for large files, or I'm using it wrong. Test code below:

```
from twisted.web import xmlrpc, server

class Example(xmlrpc.XMLRPC):
    """
    An example object to be published.
    """

    def xmlrpc_echo(self, x):
        """
        Return all passed args.
        """
        return x

    def xmlrpc_add(self, a, b):
        """
        Return sum of arguments.
        """
        return a + b

    def xmlrpc_fault(self):
        """
        Raise a Fault indicating that the procedure should not be used.
        """
        raise xmlrpc.Fault(123, "The fault procedure is faulty.")

    def xmlrpc_write(self, f, location):
        with open(location, 'wb') as fd:
            fd.write(f.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    r = Example(allowNone=True)
    reactor.listenTCP(7080, server.Site(r))
    reactor.run()
```

And the client code:

```
import xmlrpclib
s = xmlrpclib.Server('http://localhost:7080/')
with open('test.pdf', 'rb') as fd:
    f = xmlrpclib.Binary(fd.read())
s.write(f, 'output.pdf')
```

I get `xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 8002: "Can't deserialize input: ">` when I test this. Is it because the file is a pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML-RPC is a poor choice for file transfers.  XML-RPC requires the file content to be encoded in a way that XML supports.  This is expensive in both runtime costs and network resources.  Instead, try just POSTing or PUTing the file using plain old HTTP.

Comment: Ah, but I need to do stuff to the file, then return the modified file afterwards. How would I send options with the POST request, and then return the resulting file?

Comment: HTTP requests can have responses.  Send the resulting file back in the response.  HTTP requests also have a request URL, headers, and an arbitrary body.  You can stick those "options" in any of those.  Query arguments in the URL are a popular, simple option.

Comment: Argle! I'm not normally a web guy, so all of the available tools are new. I'm also trying to do this entire thing in about 4 hours. So, I"m going to go read the twisted docs on HTTP requests then. An example along the lines of what I've got would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, you're right about the HTTP being easier. I've posted another question for a problem I ran into for that, so I'll accept this answer as the way to go.